# Applying the virtual licence for HyperV server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, licensing, virtualization

I'm running **Windows Server 2008 R2** with **HyperV**.

We have a virtual image dev environment running in the virtual machine, which comes under Microsoft's licensing; one real, and one virtual machine on Windows 2008 Standard Server.

However I can't find away to apply the licence to the virtual machine, if I enter the serial number  it doesn't accept it, some mention is made of a licensing server but I can't find out much about that either. I'm not a Sysadmin, just a dev, being pelted with deadlines.

Although it is a virtual image it is a pain to have to reinstall it once a month.

So how can I make my virtual W2K8R2 accept the licence and work properly?

thanks Geoff

Comment: FWIW You can run that server for many months (I've run them for well over 3 months) before it refuses to work anymore.  It will complain a lot, but, at least in my experience they continue to function for well past the 30 day "limit".

Comment: I might be able to run for longer, but it doesn't feel right.
Our desktops are occasionally audited for licence compliance. Since I am supposed to be able to run this under my MSDN licence it would scratching an itch, me and the others in my team, to "fix it".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be applying the wrong product key.  You might want to review your licenses and make sure you've got the right keys.

Comment: I am using the licence supplied by MSDN, and since the W2k8 licence enables the server, and a single virtual OS I would have thought it would work.

Comment: Well,noly if ythe virtual server can connect to MS and you ahve activations left.

Comment: Looking at my action pack I've got physical and virtual keys for all of my server 2008 r2 licenses. Maybe check with the administrator of your MSDN account and verify that you dont have something similar?

Comment: Thanks Ernie. I have an online MSDN subscription, I can't find any mention of a Virtual key, but it is a clue towards a solution.

Comment: A call to your microsoft rep might be in order.